# How can I add bootstrap to Angular2 via system.js

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to add bootstrap module to my ng2 application with by https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap.
But all time getting this error:

[image]

It's my index file, maybe I have some mistake in my file?
index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyApplication</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>
<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### full systemjs.config

```js
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
        '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
        '@ng-bootstrap':              'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap'
    };
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    };
    var ngPackageNames = [
        'common',
        'compiler',
        'core',
        'forms',
        'http',
        'platform-browser',
        'platform-browser-dynamic',
        'router',
        'router-deprecated',
        'upgrade',
    ];
    // Individual files (~300 requests):
    function packIndex(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Bundled (~40 requests):
    function packUmd(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
    var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
    // Add package entries for angular packages
    ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    };
    System.config(config);
})(this);
```

Comment: Seems that you didn't set up system js config.

Comment: I created systemjs.config

Comment: Post it in your answer.

Comment: I added my systemjs.config

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same issue. Basically you need to tell your systemjs.config where to find all the single components of ng-bootstrap.

Based on the Answer of ulubeyn, I added the following to the basic systemjs.config:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app': 'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
    '@ng-bootstrap': 'node_modules/@ng-bootstrap',
    '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app': {main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
    'rxjs': {defaultExtension: 'js'},
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
    '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'}

  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];

  var ngBootstrapPackageNames = [
    'accordion',
    'alert',
    'bundles',
    'buttons',
    'carousel',
    'collapse',
    'dropdown',
    'esm',
    'modal',
    'pagination',
    'popover',
    'progressbar',
    'rating',
    'tabset',
    'timepicker',
    'tooltip',
    'typeahead',
    'util'
  ];
  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'};
  }

  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = {main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js'};
  }

  function ngBootstrapPackIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/' + pkgName] = {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'};
  }

  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
  ngBootstrapPackageNames.forEach(ngBootstrapPackIndex);

  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

In Detail:

1. Add `'@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'` to your map. This will provide a path to your ng-bootstrap.
2. Add `'@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }` to your packages.
3. Add a new array providing all ng-bootstrap component folders (see ngBootstrapPackageNames in the above example).
4. Now bring everything together by adding those informations to your map, and associating it with the corresponding index files:

   ```
   function ngBootstrapPackIndex(pkgName) {
      packages['@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/' + pkgName] = {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'};
   }
   ngBootstrapPackageNames.forEach(ngBootstrapPackIndex);
   ```

I hope this helps, as it works with those changes for me.

**Update for ng-bootstrap alpha 5**

If you are using alpha 5, change `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` mapping in `packages` variable to this;

```
var packages = {
     ...,
     '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': {main: '/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
     ...
}
```

Comment: what I need to change in my index file?
Because my style broken?

Comment: ng-bootstrap needs a bootstrap.css. As far as I can see, your import for this stylesheet is currently commented and therefor not imported ... On another note: Your import uses a Bootstrap v3. I Don't know if this works, as ng-boostrap officialy uses Bootstrap v4.

Comment: I'm found bootstrap.css inside node_modules > bootstrap > dist > css

Comment: I had to change the packages for ng-bootstrap to the following:

'@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': {format:'cjs',  main: 'bundles/ng-bootstrap.js', defaultExtension: 'js'}

Answer (score 4):

Your systemjs file should looks like this:

```
var ngBootstrapMap = {
    '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': '../lib/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap' //change the path according to your project structure
}

var ngBootstrapPackages = {
    '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
};

var ngBootstrapPackageNames = [
    'accordion',
    'alert',
    'bundles',
    'buttons',
    'carousel',
    'collapse',
    'dropdown',
    'esm',
    'modal',
    'pagination',
    'popover',
    'progressbar',
    'rating',
    'tabset',
    'timepicker',
    'tooltip',
    'typeahead',
    'util'
];

function ngBootstrapPackIndex(pkgName) {
    ngBootstrapPackages['@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/' + pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
}

ngBootstrapPackageNames.forEach(ngBootstrapPackIndex);

var ngBootstrapConfig = {
    map: ngBootstrapMap,
    packages: ngBootstrapPackages
};

System.config(ngBootstrapConfig);
```

Basically, it looks for index.js file in @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap folder, and after for each component it looks index.js file in @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/{componentName}

I hope it helps you