# Getting started Angular2 RC5 with ng-bootstrap 404 Error

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have followed the instructions for installation on the ng-bootstrap website with a fresh git clone of Angular2, but receive a 404 Error when NgbModule is in the import array of `@NgModule`.

Screencap of error: [404 Error loading @ng-bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzYD8.png)

Steps:

1. Cloned Angular2's quickstart git repo github.com/angular/quickstart
2. Edit `app.module.ts`  to the following:

   ```
   import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
   import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

   import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
   import { NgbModule } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

   @NgModule({
     imports: [ NgbModule, BrowserModule ],
     declarations: [ AppComponent ],
     bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
   })
   export class AppModule { }
   ```
3. Make sure `bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.3`, ng-bootstrap and angular2 RC5 are installed
4. Add bootstrap .css and .js script tags to `index.html`
5. `npm start` produces Loading... page and nothing else, can see 404 error in web console

The same occurs when trying to set the import path explicitly through node_module eg. `import { NgbModule } from "../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";`

Any help appreciated.

## Update 1:

Added @ng-bootstrap line to project root file **systemjs.config.js**. Similar 404 error in browser console.

**systemjs.config.js**:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {

  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',

    '@ng-bootstrap':              'node_modules/@ng-bootstrap',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
  };

  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };

  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade'
  ];

  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }

  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }

  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;

  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);

  // No umd for router yet
  packages['@angular/router'] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };

  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };

  System.config(config);

})(this);
```

## Update 2

Added the index.js file to the packages in **systemjs.config.js** and am receiving errors on the individual files as per screencap [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn5vl.png):

**systemjs.config.js (excerpt)**

```
 //packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution. Problem indeed lies in **systemjs.config.js**. Followed instructions and now the issue is fixed. Thanks

[How can I add bootstrap to Angular2 via system.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894549/how-can-i-add-bootstrap-to-angular2-via-system-js)

Comment: thanks, after 3 hours of banging my head this solution worked for me

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have not added the path of `@ng-bootstrap` in the systemjs configuration,

Add path for `@ng-bootstrap` in **systemjs.config.js**

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hi @madhu-ranjan, I added a line in the map array. This produced the same 404 error. The new line in my systemjs.config.js map array is
`'@ng-bootstrap':              'node_modules/@ng-bootstrap',`

Comment: Please Add your system config in your question for reference.

Comment: @Nelson Include the main file in the packages as well for ng2-bootstrap.

Comment: I've added this line to the packages `'@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap':              { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },` and now it's struggling to load the individual components, Carousel, Buttons etc. Updated original post with screencap

Comment: Still 404 not found, see screencap http://i.stack.imgur.com/kn5vl.png. From what I can see it seems require is trying to fetch modules from the @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap folder instead of looking into the relevant children folders...?